# SCOPE_IDENTITY does not seem to work with parameterized queries

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a table with an identity column whose value I would like to get after an INSERT. The following code, which does not use parameters, is working perfectly:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO aTable ([aColumn]) VALUES (42)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

query = "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)";
command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
object identity = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

If I change the INSERT part of the above code to use a parameterized query, `ExecuteScalar()` suddenly returns a `System.DBNull` value. This is how the parameterized query code looks like:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO aTable ([aColumn]) VALUES (@aColumn)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aColumn", 42);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have tried to change the SCOPE_IDENTITY code so that it uses an output parameter and invokes `ExecuteNonQuery()`, but I still get a null value in the out parameter. I have also tried running the code against two different versions of SQL Server (2012 and 2008, both Express Edition), again with the same result.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Parameterised queries probably wind up calling `sp_executesql`. That runs in a child scope and when it exits `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is null in the outer scope.

Comment: In addition to combining them into a single batch, another workaround would be to stop embedding dynamic SQL in your app, and put this logic in a stored procedure.

Comment: You could also try `INSERT INTO aTable(...) OUTPUT Inserted.ID VALUES(.....)` to automatically output all inserted new `ID` values.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, that nicely explains why the answer I accepted is working and my code is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try combining your INSERT and SELECT into one statement

```
string query = "INSERT INTO aTable ([aColumn]) VALUES (@aColumn);SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)"; 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aColumn", 42); 
object identity = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: To a neophyte like me that seems amazing, but together with Martin Smith's comment this actually makes sense :-) Anyway, thanks a lot!